# How to create reusable for loop with try catch?

Tags: php, for-loop

here is the code i'm using:

```
for ($i=0; $i < 2; $i++) {
    try {
        User::create([
            'name' => 'username'
        ]);
        break;
    } catch (\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e) {
        if ($i == 1) {
            throw $e;
        }
    }
}
```

but i want to make reusable this code only substitute data in try loop for example:

```
for ($i=0; $i < 2; $i++) {
    try {

        // replace something here
        // all rest of the code should be ignore and resuable

        break;
    } catch (\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e) {
        if ($i == 1) {
            throw $e;
        }
    }
}
```

it could be use case something like this:

```
loop(function() {
    User::create([
        'name' => 'user name'
    ]);
})
```

any solution?

Answer (score 0):

From PHP 5.3.0 you can pass function as argument of a function. So you can put your for loop into some function and when you call it pass other function (piece of code you wanna change).

For example (not tested):

```
function loopingFucntion($someOtherFunction){
    for ($i=0; $i < 2; $i++) {
        try {
    $someOtherFunction();
            break;
        } catch (\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e) {
            if ($i == 1) {
                throw $e;
            }
        }
    }
}

//and when you wanna pass your new code you can call it like this
loopingFucntion(function(){
    //your new code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do pretty much exactly what you're saying by passing an anonymous function in as a parameter and then running it inside the for loop.  The top code will just go in to a function

```
function loop($func)
{
    for ($i=0; $i < 2; $i++)
    {
        try
        {
            $func();
        }
        catch (\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e)
        {
            if ($i == 1)
                throw $e;
        }
    }
}

loop(function()
{
    echo "LOOPING" . "\n";
});
```

This outputs "LOOPING" twice.